# jQuery: preview images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a high-quality image and I want to generate **img** tag with this image.
The problem is that it will take a lot of time to load this image.
So the question is: how can I reduce image's quality without creating another one with low quality?

Comment: You can't increase the loading time because you want a smaller image from the larger image so you need to read the larger image first and there is your loading time again. But it would be possible to generate a smaller image with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I reduce image's quality without creating another one with low quality?

And the answer is: you can't. If you want to reduce bandwidth you could provide thumbnails for the actual images. Those thumbnails could be dynamically generated from the original images using the server side language of your choice. If you don't reduce those images on the server, you are busted. Once you send them to the client you have already wasted the bandwidth. This reduction has to happen on the server if you want to gain something. You can always set the `width` and `height` attributes of the `img` tag and fool yourself that you are gaining something.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the image, `gif` or `png`, with the 'interlaced' option set, it will load in progressively greater detail, initially blurred/fuzzy and increasing resolution as more data is received from the server.

This does have the principal consequence of increased file-sizes, though.

Reference:

- [Coding Horror, by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/12/progressive-image-rendering.html).